# create iOS project to include in other projects

Tags: ios

I have a lot of code that I use for multiple apps. Currently, I have some class files that are just included in each project. They do JSON/XML processing from an API.

However, I'd like to structure my code better.

For example SDWebimage is a project you include and kinda tie into your own parent project to handle image processing stuff like late/threaded image loading and such.

I would like to do this so I can make updates to my core projects (that do the heavy lifting like send/receive/parse JSON/XML from an API for a CMS) and not have to then update all my code in the other projects.

I know I can include .m/.h files from, say, a central folder and uncheck 'copy to project' so many projects can then reference one pair of .m/.h files

but.. I'd like to expand my knowledge and have a separate project for each specific form of workload like a good MVC style program should be. Or is that too much for such little code?

Thanks

Comment: Look into creating a static library for the code that you like to reuse. Also looking creating a workspace in Xcode. You can have multiple Xcode projects open in a workspace. In your case, attached the static library and the project that uses it into the workspace.

Comment: ahh, static library. I'll give that a whirl. Thanks